# Spring Boot RestTemplate: Error 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jax-rs, resttemplate

I was using below code to call one REST web API,

```
WebTarget target = client.target(CommonConfig.getProperty(APIX_SEND_EMAIL_URL));
Response response = target.request("application/json")
                          .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                          .header("Authorization", token)
                          .post(Entity.json(email));
```

Now I want to use Spring Boot RestTemplate to call this web service, and I am using below code:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
List<MediaType> mediaList = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
mediaList.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
mediaList.add(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
headers.setAccept(mediaList);
//Json is the json object of the request data
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(json.toString(), headers);

ResponseEntity<String> loginResponse = restTemplate
                  .exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
```

But I get error *415 Unsupported Media Type*. Can anyone help me understand what cause of mistake, How I can fix it with RestTemplate?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use postForObject() method of RestTemplate?

```
SomeObject json = SomeObject();
SomeOtherObject response = restTemplate.postForObject("url", json , SomeOtherObject.class);
```